# Content of UITableViewCell falling outside of cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've been fiddling around for a bit to try and get this to work but for some reason I can't get the content in this tableView to stay inside the cell.
The following image is a screenshot of my storyboard where I define the tableView. You can see that there is amble space.

[image: Storyboard]

But then in the simulator you can see that the content is leaking out of the cell into other cells.

If I scroll then the cells crop the text but do not grow in height.

[image: Simulator]

Not sure what kind of information will help out with this.

I have constraints added to the cells defining height, not width, as well as trailing edges and tops of the cells. Nothing crazy that should be causing this.

I'm defining the row height in the storyboard as such:

[image: Defining row height]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your row height from your TableView attributes inspector and uncheck the "Custom" option in your UITableViewCell as you show above.

[image]